# Why can the code be compiled when I add a redundant comma in parameter?

Tags: android-studio

I use Android Studio Arctic Fox, the Code A is from the [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs).

And Code A is can be compiled correctly. I find that Code B can also be compiled creeclty when I add a redundant comma in parameter list, why?

**Code A**

```
composable(Bills.name) {
            BillsBody(bills = UserData.bills)
        }
```

**Code B**

```
composable(Bills.name, ) {
            BillsBody(bills = UserData.bills)
        }
```

**The same**

```
public fun NavGraphBuilder.composable(
    route: String,
    arguments: List<NamedNavArgument> = emptyList(),
    deepLinks: List<NavDeepLink> = emptyList(),
    content: @Composable (NavBackStackEntry) -> Unit
) {
    addDestination(
        ComposeNavigator.Destination(provider[ComposeNavigator::class], content).apply {
            this.route = route
            arguments.forEach { (argumentName, argument) ->
                addArgument(argumentName, argument)
            }
            deepLinks.forEach { deepLink ->
                addDeepLink(deepLink)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called trailing comma and was added in Kotlin [version 1.4](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew14.html#trailing-comma).

One of the main reasons behind trailing commas - using them reduces the amount of lines you need to update when the list length changes. Makes commits a bit cleaner.